# Why does adding a HStack inside a VStack wreck size calculations for a ZStack bubble around text elements?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-zstack

I want to produce a bubble-like view with various pieces of text on a rounded rectangle background, sized to fit the text. I have arrived at this:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                Color.blue
                VStack{
                    Text(message.content)
                        .padding(.all, .oneUnit)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                }
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
        }
    }
```

When that is repeated with a `ForEach` and some text passed in as message, content is almost right but the `ZStack` background should only be big enough to cover the text, making a bubble:

[image: ZStack is too large - full width though text is small]

Using `.layoutPriority` fixes this, code becomes:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                Color.blue
                VStack{
                    Text(message.content)
                        .padding(.all, .oneUnit)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                }
                .layoutPriority(1)
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
        }
    }
```

[image: Correct size - fits text]

So the size of the `ZStack` is the size required to fit the text. Great! Now to put all the required pieces of text in the `VStack`. Let's add one more `Text`:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                Color.blue
                VStack{
                    Text(message.content)
                        .padding(.all, .oneUnit)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    Text("Out damned spot!")
                }
                .layoutPriority(1)
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
        }
    }
```

Text display underneath, sizing still correct.

[image: VStack with two text elements is correctly sized]

But that last piece of text has to be right-aligned. So then the code is:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                Color.blue
                VStack{
                    Text(message.content)
                        .padding(.all, .oneUnit)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Out damned spot!")
                    }
                }
                .layoutPriority(1)
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
        }
    }
```

And then everything is broken. Can anyone say why the `HStack` breaks the `ZStack`'s size?

[image: ZStack becomes full-width - incorrect!]

Comment: When working with SwiftUI I like to think of its components as water. If there is the possibility to take up space, water will take that space. In your case adding a `Spacer()` to the  `HStack` results in the `HStack` taking all the available space. You can use a trailing alignment for the `VStack` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@SwissMark** is right, the cause of your problem is that `Spacer()` is greedy, it takes all the space left. Making your bubbles the max size possible. But only making `VStack` alignment `.trailing` doesn't do the trick.

Problems:

1. Your background is Set in the `ZStack`
2. layoutPriority doesn't make any sense here

Here is the solution:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var messages = [
        "I heard the owl scream and the crickets cry.",
        "Out damned spot!",
        "Did not you speak?",
        "Out damned spot!",
        "When?",
        "Out damned spot!",
        "Now.",
        "Out damned spot!"
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        Text(messages[0])
                            .padding(.all, 4)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        Text(messages[1])
                            .padding([.bottom, .trailing], 4)
                    }
                    .padding(4)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        Text(messages[2])
                            .padding(.all, 4)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        Text(messages[3])
                            .padding([.bottom, .trailing], 4)
                    }
                    .padding(4)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        Text(messages[4])
                            .padding(.all, 4)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        Text(messages[5])
                            .padding([.bottom, .trailing], 4)
                    }
                    .padding(4)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        Text(messages[6])
                            .padding(.all, 4)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        Text(messages[7])
                            .padding([.bottom, .trailing], 4)
                    }
                    .padding(4)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Final image:

[image]

Modify the paddings and spaces as you wish.